# Google Drive API sending PDF attachments in emails

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, sendgrid

I have some node.js code that reads in a PDF file using Google Drive API **drive.files.get()**... (it's a file that is sourced on our Google team/shared drives).  I convert the returned stream to a single base64 data chunk with something like this:

```
    // read using drive.files.get() into 'pdfStream'
    //...
    let pdf64 = '';

    pdfSream.on('readable', function () { 
      var chunk = pdfStream.read();

      if (chunk != null) {
        var chunk64 = chunk.toString('base64');
        pdf64 += chunk64;
      }
    });
    pdfStream.on('end', function () {
      // Do SendGrid email with pdf64 as attachment
    });
```

Note that the final goal is to send an email with the PDF.  I haven't included much of the code because this all works great - **as long as the email recipient is on our company's domain**.  For external email recipients, the PDF attachment is unviewable and cannot be downloaded - at least this is what the situation appears to be.

I didn't think that access-restrictions and permissions would stay with data that is read directly using drive.files.get().  Is this a thing?  I would suspect SendGrid except that we send attachments in other areas of our code with no issue.

Thoughts anyone?  Much appreciated!
~Bob

Comment: Hi, consider providing the parts of the code where the file is retrieved from Drive and how it's sent as an attachment, in order to fully understand this situation and troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it.  The permissions thing was a red herring - the pdf attachments were corrupt and our company email system was just more lenient with the errors than others (like Gmail).  I refactored the above code to first create a complete array of data, then converted that array to base64:

```
    // read using drive.files.get() into 'pdfStream'
    //...
    let pdfChunks = [];

    // Read through stream chunks and concat them together
    pdfStream.on('readable', function () {
      var chunk = pdfStream.read();

      if (chunk != null) {
        pdfChunks.push(chunk);
      }
    });
    // On the end of the stream, convert to base64 and email the Pdf
    pdfStream.once('end', function () {
      let pdfBin = Buffer.concat(pdfChunks);
      let pdf64 = pdfBin.toString('base64');
      //...
      // Do SendGrid email with pdf64 as attachment
    });
```

Cheers!
~Bob